# Join and sum with Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

and

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

How do I make a simple join between these two models? I want all the objects in Model1 with the sum of prices from all objects in Model2 which are related to the specific Model1-object.

I guess it's something like

```
queryset = Model1.objects.annotate(model2_price=Sum(price)).values('name','model2_price')
```

Comment: What's missing from your query? It seems you answered your own question, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close with using annotation. Just use a valid lookup string in `Sum()` and you're done:

```
queryset = Model1.objects.annotate(model2_price=Sum('model1__price'))

for m in queryset:
    print m.model2_price
```

**EDIT**:

I overlooked that it's a `ForeignKey` from `Model2` to `Model1`, but that is absolutely no problem. In the models, Django automatically adds the reverse relations for all `OneToOneField`s, `ForeignKey`s and `ManyToManyField`s. You can pass the `related_name` parameter to each of these fields to alter the attribute name of the reverse relation, but by default it will be `<lowercase_modelname>_set`. So what you need to do now is:

```
queryset = Model1.objects.annotate(model2_price=Sum('model2_set__price'))
```

What I generally recommend is to explicitly define a related name and use that to refer to the related object, to avoid any confusion as to what the attribute name is, and possibly provide a more descriptive name for the relation:

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, related_name='model2')
    price = models.IntegerField()

queryset = Model1.objects.annotate(model2_price=Sum('model2__price'))
```

**EDIT 2**:
The result of the query cannot be modified, annotation doesn't support more complex queries. There are several ways to work around this, I like this one the most:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    @property
    def model2_total_price(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_model2_total_price'):
            raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute 'model2_total_price'" % self.__class__.__name__)
        if self._model2_total_price:
            return self._model2_total_price
        return 0

queryset = Model1.objects.annotate(_model2_total_price=Sum('model2_set__price'))

for m in queryset:
    print m.model2_total_price
```

This will behave exactly as if you were annotating to a field called `model2_total_price`, including raising an `AttributeError` if no annotation is used at all, while still returning `0` if the `model2_set` is empty. The `@property` decorator allows you to use an instance method as if it were a regular attribute (although you can't set it without supplying an additional setter method). The starting underscore in `_model2_total_price` tells other developers to keep away from that attribute unless they know exactly what they're doing and why they want to change that (substitute for a proper 'private' attribute in other languages, without enforcing it - the Pythonesque way of doing it).

The only thing you have to make sure of is to always use the exact same attribute name for your annotations: `_model2_total_price` in this example.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. The objects are only linked from model 2 to model 1, so I don't think I can use model1__price or am I wrong?

Comment: @Jamgreen: that's absolutely no problem, check my edit.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you..

Is it possible to return 0 if the model2_set 'is empty'? Right now it prints "None". It is no problem in my normal templates, but in one of my views, I return the queryset as json, so it would be perfect if I shouldn't check for None values in javascript